# How do I split on a regex and get my elements into an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, split

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  Is there any way I can split on a regex and get the resulting elements in an array?  I thought this was the way

```
2.4.0 :003 > word = "4.ARTHUR"
 => "4.ARTHUR" 
2.4.0 :004 > word.split(/^\d+\./)
 => ["", "ARTHUR"]
```

but as you see, the first element of my array is an empty string despite the fact that the pattern matches.  I would like the output to be

```
["4.", "ARTHUR"]
```

Comment: Do mean you need `4.` to be in the array? Try `word.split(/^(\d+\.)/)`

Comment: THat definitely gets me a little closer.  Now the array is ["", "4.", "ARTHUR"]  .  Is there any way to make it so that it only has the two elements in there?

Comment: Remove them: `word.split(/^(\d+\.)/).reject { |c| c.empty? }`

Comment: Do you mean you want `"4.ARCHIE".split('.') #=> ["4", "ARCHIE"]` or `"4.ARCHIE".split(/\./) #=> ["4", "ARCHIE"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-split) splits the string where a match is found. So, `^\d+\.` matches `4.` in `4.ARTHUR` at the beginning and thus, the result is an empty string (the beginning of the string)  and `ARTHUR`. To keep the match obtained during `split` operation with a regex, you need to wrap the whole pattern with a capturing group and to get rid of the empty items, you can just remove them later:

```
word.split(/^(\d+\.)/).reject { |x| x.empty? }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do

```
irb(main):004:0> word = "4.ARTHUR"
=> "4.ARTHUR"
irb(main):005:0> word.split('.')
=> ["4", "ARTHUR"]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to split up a string but keep all of its parts, [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html) is often a better fit than `String#split`:

```
word = "4.ARTHUR"
word.scan(/^\d+\.|.+/)
# => ["4.", "ARTHUR"]
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/F90q

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a, b = word.match(/^(\d+\.)?(.*)/).captures
```

The `split` method is meant to be used with a separator, as for example a comma. What you are doing is splitting the string into two parts without a separator, just use capture groups.